# firefox console warning running meteor app

Tags: firefox, meteor

This Meteor app runs but firefox console reports the following. Is there a problem to fix? Thanks

> The connection to ws://localhost:3000/sockjs/916/95ub_dkm/websocket was interrupted while the page was loading. ddp-client.js:1363:14
>   mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create
>
> mutating the [[Prototype]] of an object will cause your code to run very slowly; instead create the object with the correct initial [[Prototype]] value using Object.create